# how do I install a plugin in wordpress without admin access

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to install a plugin in Wordpress even I haven't admin access. This question has been raised in the interview. I responded as `No` because a CMS can't provide space for security beach.
I am curious to know that is it really possible?

Comment: I think (don't trying) is enough simple copy plugin to plugin folder and, possibly, update DB with SQL... But is a way to deaktivate plugin, if all messed up - just remove plugin.

Comment: Why are you asking this in the first place, what's your situation? Maybe there's a different workaround

Comment: A CMS shouldn't provide space for security breaches but it's wordpress you're talking about here. WP is constantly under attack and exploits are found often enough. Especially since anyone can make a plugin for it.

Comment: If a user has DB and FTP access then he would be the administrator. Then there would not be any meaning of this question.

Comment: After all the discussion, looks like the person /company asked the question is totally meaningless. They just tried to testing the security features of Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to if you have access to the DB, or/and if you have write access to the filesystem (through FTP for example). But not through the web interface.

Comment: Though if you have physical access to the server, might as well just go ahead and give yourself admin access ;-)

Comment: What does you mean by physical access? Is it FTP access?

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's a good point. With FTP or DB access you could add a new user and problem solved

Comment: Physical access meaning you can read/write Wordpress' PHP files directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you had FTP access you could use the activate_plugin() function. There's very little information out there about this function but it looks fairly simple.

Consider using a function like plugin_basename() to get the path you need.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename

```
activate_plugin( '/path/to/plugin/file' );
```

Comment: Can you describe your answer?

Comment: Sure, all you need is to get the absolute path to the plugin file. Pass that to activate_plugin and the plugin will be activated. I'll update my answer with an example